# What is the eigenvector here?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

To find the eigenvector $(x_1,x_2)$, I reduce $Ax=\lambda x$ to
$$\begin{align}
(d_0+v_{01}-\lambda_1)x_1-v_{01}x_2=0\\
-v_{10}x_1+(v_{10}-\lambda_1)x_2=0,\\
\end{align}$$ where $$\lambda_{1,2}=\dfrac{d_0+v_{01}+v_{10}\pm\sqrt{(d_0+v_{01}+v_{10})^2-4d_0v_{10}}}{2}.$$ The variables $d_0,v_{01},v_{10}$ are positive. How do I find $(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: Choose a value for $x_2$, say $1$, then plug it into, say, the second equation and solve for $x_1$. So $\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{v_{10}}{v_{10}-\lambda} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: if you know all the quantities besides $x_1, x_2$ in the above equations, then you just have a linear system: $$ \begin{bmatrix} d_0 + v_{01} - \lambda_1 & v_{01} \\ -v_{10} & v_{10} - \lambda_1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}. $$ You can use Gaussian elimination to solve.